# Android API inconsistency with renderscript.type class

Tags: android, api, types, renderscript

I am using android.support.v8.renderscript API, and I want to use the static function ‘createX’ of the class ‘Type’.
It seems that ‘createX’ does not exist in ‘Type’! And when I use it, I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'createX(android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript, android.support.v8.renderscript.Element, int)'
```

But when I change the API to android.renderscript, it seems ok, and no error occurs.
I have these lines in my build.gradle:

```
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I am supposed to use android.support.v8.renderscript, not android.renderscript.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use `renderscriptTargetApi 19` rather than target `22`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Type.createX()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Type.html#createX(android.renderscript.RenderScript,%20android.renderscript.Element,%20int)) was only added in API 21. As you are using `renderscriptTargetApi 19`, you only get access to API 19 Renderscript methods - change it to target the latest (at this time, `22`) to use methods introduced in later API levels. Note that all methods are supported back to API 8.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I encountered another error that I explained it above. Please help me if you can.

Comment: The compatibility library only works for versions 8 - 19, so you can't use this method. That said, you can get the same functionality by just creating a Type.Builder (combined with setX/create).

Comment: @StephenHines - [Type.createX()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/Type.html#createX(android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript,%20android.support.v8.renderscript.Element,%20int)) does exist in the support library Renderscript API so I'm not sure what you mean by 'you can't use this method'? The difference between 8-19 and higher is only in swapping to native Renderscript and that doesn't affect availability of Renderscript APIs?

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize that one of my coworkers made this work for all users of the support library.